# The size of points does not always seem relevant with the size of other points in chart

Tags: r, plotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
bt<-structure(list(year2 = c(1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 
1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015), issue = c("health", 
"health", "health", "health", "health", "health", "health", "health", 
"health", "health", "health", "health", "health"), country = c("EU", 
"EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU", 
"EU"), pta_count = c(1, 3, 5, 12, 10, 2, 2, 14, 13, 9, 8, 6, 
5), value = c(NA, 2, 4, 11, 7, 1, 2, 13, 12, 9, 8, 6, 5), x = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), percent = c(NA, 0.666666666666667, 0.8, 
0.916666666666667, 0.7, 0.5, 1, 0.928571428571429, 0.923076923076923, 
1, 1, 1, 1), percvalue = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

and Im trying to create a dot plot in which the grey circle represents always the `100%` of `value` this is why it is always `1` and the green circle inside should represent the `percent` (`value/pta_count`). The problem is that the green circles do not seem to be relevant to their value.For example `50%` has a very small green circle compared to the grey circle and compared to `66.67%` as well. I do not know what the issue is. Maybe I should use another value in the y-axis.

```
f <- bt   %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year2)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percvalue, size = percvalue, text = paste0("Year: ", year2)),
             color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(y = percvalue, size = percent,
                 # text = paste0("Year: ", year2, "\nPercent: ", round(percent, 3) * 100, "%")), 
                 text = paste0("Year: ", year2, "\nPercentage of all signed PTAs covering NTIs: ", scales::percent(percent))), 
             color = "darkolivegreen") +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 14) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position  =  'none',
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could multiply the proportions by a fixed amount (say 8, though you can use whatever number suits you to make your data clear), and use `scale_size_identity`. This ensures the size of the dots is always proportional to their value.

```r
ggplot(bt, aes(x = year2, y = percvalue)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = 8 * percvalue), color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(size = 8 * percent), color = "darkolivegreen") +
  geom_text(aes(y = percvalue, label = scales::percent(percent, 1)),
            nudge_y = 0.25, size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 14) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2)) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position  =  'none',
        axis.title.y     = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y      = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "")
```

[image]

Comment: @firmo23 I've updated to add the percentage labels too, so if you don't want them just remove the `geom_text` call.

Comment: seems useful but when I use it inside ggplotly() the percentages are displayed at the top and the circles at the bottom. if they can be displayed as in ggplot I want it

Comment: @firmo23 did you not add in the `scale_y_continuous` line? It should prevent that from happening.

Comment: yes u are right